# Why don't browsers include the jQuery library to avoid being loaded on every website?

Tags: jquery, browser

I've recently got into jQuery development of dynamic web apps or websites and I have this question regarding it.

Simply, why don't browsers include the jQuery library to avoid delays and obtain a better website loading speed?

I know the library is somehow cached and it won't be loaded every time the user hits `<script src="jquery.js"></script>` but wouldn't it be better if every user has it inside the browser?

Comment: Common CDN's like "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" do pretty much what you want. Everyone that uses that "src" will get the script from the same place meaning once it has been downloaded once then it is cached. Adding every "important" script to a browser would cause way more trouble than the few milliseconds saved would really be worth.

Answer (score 2):

There are some logical reasons browsers do not include jQuery:

- jQuery is only one JS library in an infinite expanse of libraries
- A browser doesn't/shouldn't care about bloated libraries or versioning

If you don't want to clients to have to download your copy of the common framework you chose to use then point to a [CDN](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/).

Comment: I would upvote if not for the last point. For starters, Angular.js and jQuery technically don't exclude each other.

Comment: More than that, they have completely different purposes

Comment: Edited to be more accurate based on comments from @JanDvorak.